# can't create a sql database "error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred". (Visual Studio Enterprise 2015)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I can't create an SQL database,every time I create a Microsoft SQL database, an error message appears

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process
>   failed to start. ) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1983577846)

I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio with SQL Server, but it didn't work.
Help me with a detailed explanation to fix it

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this link could help you: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30383/cannot-start-sqllocaldb-instance-with-my-windows-account

Comment: I try it but error on cmd "Start of LocalDB instance "v11.0" failed because of the following error:
Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details." @raBinn

Comment: could you show log details, please